# Participants of the Channel are not able to join the Meeting

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-teams, graph-api, beta

I created an online meeting using graph API in my one of the channel in the Teams.

I am following the example given [Create Online Meeting in the channel of the team](https://github.com/paywuAtMicrosoft/microsoft-graph-docs/blob/paywu/3323-calling-onlinemeeting-update/api-reference/beta/api/application-post-onlinemeetings.md)

Below are the API request and its body.

Request: `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/onlineMeetings/`

Body:

```
{
  "startDateTime":"2019-10-30T06:45:00Z",
  "endDateTime":"2019-10-30T06:50:00Z",
  "subject":"Test Meeting",
  "chatInfo": {
    "threadId":"19:b4d5de0853d945ccb6eaf691fc0caa74@thread.skype"
  },
  "accessLevel":"everyone"
}
```

The meeting is created successfully and it is also shown on the channel. **However, users are not able to join the meeting by clicking on it as nothing happens when the user clicks on the meeting.**

[image]

Can anyone let me know what am I missing here?